# Vue Dialog execute whenever activated/called

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dialog

I have following dialog in my compoenent:

```
<v-dialog v-model="orderDetailsDialogVisible" max-width="900px">
    <OrderDetailsDialog v-bind="{selectedOrder:selectedOrder, source:source}"></OrderDetailsDialog>
</v-dialog>
```

`orderDetailsDialogVisible` is set to `true`, when user clicks on button. before that the parameters `selectedOrder` and `source` are set.

When the user clicks anywhere else outside the dialog, the dialog disappears.

In my dialog I need to make a REST Call, **every time** the dialogue is shown.

**I do not know where to put it.** When I put it in `beforeMount` it is only executed the first time the dialog appears. When the dialog disappears and appears again the `beforeMount` is not called. Also `updated` does not work in the sense that the code updates the model which in turn calls `updated` which then ends up in an endless loop.

Comment: Cant you put it in the button click handling procedure?

Comment: yes thats an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mounted` event for the initialization. And you can use the `watch` for the updates:

The code would be that way:

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    orderDetailsDialogVisible: false,
  }),
  watch: {
    orderDetailsDialogVisible(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue) {
        this.requestApi();
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    requestApi() {
      console.log('requestApi');
      // axios.get...
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.requestApi();
  },
};
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I havent found time to try it yet